# No one feeds a starving dog - is it a saying?

Tags: british-english, popular-refrains

I grew up in a small down full of orginal settlers and kin from england- This was  saying in our small town - did it originate with us, or does it have origins elsewhere.

Comment: What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: I’ve never heard it and am not sure what it means either.

Comment: One example of the string seems to have appeared on the internet, according to a Google search. It appears highly localised.

Comment: It's not a phrase used often by dogs who have starved, for some reason.

Comment: I've never heard it (in the US Midwest).  Seems like something of a tautology.

Comment: I'm British and I've never heard it before.

Answer (score 2):

I'm from Kent in England and I've heard this saying before. It means if a person (represented by the dog) is desperately in need of help then you should be careful about helping them as they may keep coming back to you expecting more and more. Not the nicest of proverbs really but there's some sense in it. We say it 'never feed a hungry dog' and, although it's not a common saying, it's probably known all over the UK.

Comment: add a citation to enhance your answer

Answer (score 0):

I found two famous sayings related to feeding (or not feeding) starving dogs. The first is attributed to Mohandas Gandhi, in Louis Fischer, [*The Life of Mahatma Gandhi*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8qwqAAAAYAAJ&q=%22insult+to+a+starving+dog%22&dq=%22insult+to+a+starving+dog%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOj43H2rbSAhUQyWMKHeQKBmoQ6AEIOzAF) (1950):

> He [Gandhi] reasoned thus: **It is a sin to feed stray dogs.** "It is a false sense of compassion. **It is an insult to a starving dog to throw a crumb at him.** Roving dogs do not indicate the civilization or compassion of the society, they betray on the contrary the ignorance and lethargy of its members. ..."

From Mark Twain, [*Pudd'nhead Wilson*](https://books.google.com/books?id=goWwAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22principal+difference+between+a+dog%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIkI3Y3bbSAhVJwlQKHU4uAuIQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22principal%20difference%20between%20a%20dog%22&f=false), (1894):

> "**If you pick up a starving dog and make him prosperous, and he will not bite you.** This is the principal difference between a dog and a man."

Neither of these quotations seems very apt to the saying you cite. However, James Howell, [*Lexicon Tetraglotton, an English-French-Italian-Spanish Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PCtWAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA8-PA17&dq=%22If+you+will+have+the+dog+follow+you,+give+him+bread%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiltI_n-7bSAhXpwVQKHThdDEoQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22If%20you%20will%20have%20the%20dog%20follow%20you%2C%20give%20him%20bread%22&f=false) (1660) mentions an old Spanish proverb that may be relevant:

> **If you will have the dog follow you, give him bread.**

The negative side of this advice would seem to be, if you don't want a starving dog to follow you, don't feed it.

Another interesting dog proverb appears in John Ray, [*A Collection of English Proverbs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rnlQoxh95VMC&pg=PA63&dq=%22One+year+of+joy,+another+of+comfort,+and+all+the+rest+of+content%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yok5VOHUKcX5iwKY74GICA#v=snippet&q=When%20a%20Dog%20is%20drowning&f=false) (1678):

> **When a Dog is drowning every one offers him water.**

Which is sort of like saying, "When a dog is starving, every one wants to put him on a diet."

Still, I haven't been able to turn up anything truly similar to the expression you ask about.